# Linux bash unzip only one files with archive file zip

Tags: linux, bash

I have zip file = file.zip, inside are

f1.txt

f2.txt

f3.txt

...

and i need unpack only f2.txt in linux bash.

Comment: Did you read the `unzip` man page?

Comment: I cannot find this options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unzip -j file.zip f2.txt -d "/destination/path"